# "expectation" VS "expectations"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. Near-term sentiment has shifted to the euro, amid market **expectations** that the Federal Reserve will put brakes on raising rates.
> 2. Near-term sentiment has shifted to the euro, amid market **expectation** that the Federal Reserve will put brakes on raising rates.

Is one of the above sentences more appropriate than the other?

Answer (score 1):

The first of your sentences is probably from the article [Heraeus Precious Forecast 6th February 2019](https://www.heraeus.com/media/media/hpm/doc_hpm/precious_metal_update/forecast_1/HPM_EM_Forecast_EN.pdf);

> **Near-term sentiment has shifted to the euro, amid market *[expectations](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expectation)*
>   that the Federal Reserve will stop raising rates.** However, US job
>   numbers are still good, so one more rate rise is possible which would
>   benefit the dollar. Additionally, economic growth seems to be slowing
>   more in Europe than in the US, which also favours dollar strength this
>   year, since the ECB will most likely delay making its first rate rise.

---

[amid](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/amid) (*prep*; *in the middle of or surrounded by*) is either followed by a plural-countable noun, a collective noun, or an uncountable noun. For example;

> a brief moment of levity **amid** the solemn **proceedings**
>
> Her office was an oasis of peace and sanity **amid** the surrounding
>   **chaos**.
>
> The town sits **amid** gentle **hills** and dense forest.
>
> The actors made their bows **amid** great **applause**.
>
> The president cancelled his visit **amid** **speculation** that his health was
>   failing.

Following is an example from https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/amid;

> There, **amid** a **cluster** of floats, Boy Scouts and ballerinas,
>   four of Fred's lady friends were in the final stages of hanging
>   bunting about a beautiful old touring car whose vintage or name Dean
>   couldn't identify.

Therefore, your version of the original sentence, the second one, is incorrect.

Comment: "amid market expectation" _may_ be OK, if you consider that expectation is a bunch of smaller expectations - but I recommend to use the fully correct "amid market expectation**s**"

Comment: @virolino if someone means what you think to be considered for the singular one to be correct, they need to add 'a bunch of' otherwise that'd be a mistake because the reader won't know what the writer means. There are, however, cases like "Men have unrealistic expectations about how women should look." where singular 'expectation' would also be fine with a different context or a slightly different meaning.

Comment: As you said, amid (prep; in the middle of or surrounded by) is either followed by a plural-countable noun, a collective noun, or an uncountable noun. Why can't expectation be regarded as uncountable here?